# UICollectionView unresponsive with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have a UICollectionView which loads images from online. While the images are loading, I'd like to animate the cells. The following is making the cells become unresponsive to touch (I seem to be able to still scroll using the gaps between the cells). Any ideas?

```
class GridViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var imageViewContent = UIImageView()
    var animatedView = UIView()
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        animatedView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gridItemSize, height: gridItemSize)
        contentView.addSubview(animatedView)
        
        imageViewContent.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gridItemSize, height: gridItemSize)
        imageViewContent.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageViewContent.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleWidth]
        imageViewContent.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(imageViewContent)
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        imageViewContent.image = nil
        self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        animatedView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: TimeInterval(CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...2.0)), options:[.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.animatedView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
        }, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GridViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GridViewCell
        cell.imageViewContent.image = nil
        cell.imageViewContent.af.setImage(withURL: URL(string:"SOME IMAGE URL")
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: The `layoutSubviews()` method can be called quite frequently though and you probably don't want the start another animation every time it happens. For example, if you rotate the device, layoutSubviews() will likely be called for each cell in the collection view, even if the image is already loaded.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev thanks I'll move to init

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case anyone else runs into it. You need to add .allowUserInteraction to the options of UIView.animate:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: TimeInterval(CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...2.0)), options:[.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.animatedView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
        }, completion:nil)
```